# Can publishing good peer reviewed scientific articles be seen as a part of good academic record?

Tags: publications, research-process

I have this doubt inside my mind after graduating from my master's program. Can publishing high IF scientific articles be seen as a good academic record during masters. And will it be considered by the top world-class educational institutes to be a good academic record apart from having good marks in masters? I am asking this question as I wish to apply for technical masters and the scholarships for the same at world-class institutes.

Comment: Why are you asking? Are you looking to apply to a doctoral program or for some other reason?

Comment: Yes, only if you are the main author.  Such articles suggest you have the necessary skills to carry out high quality work.

Comment: *Can* it? Good publications are the main currency of academic achievement.

Answer (score 4):

If you apply for a PhD position, and you already have articles that are published (or accepted for publication) in "high impact" journals or conferences, that is certainly a plus.

If you apply for a job, in many cases, the people who evaluate you have no appreciation of what academic research and publishing involves and what it means to have published. (Of course, there are many exceptions to this; such as highly technical engineering and science-related jobs.) However, they still might be impressed, so I would include it in my CV.